# Laravel Query Builder Update with Increment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Hi I need to fix my query where I will need to update my product quantity with just incrementing it, here is my code with sample.

```
    DB::table('product_warehouse')
    ->where('product_id', $product_id)
    ->where('warehouse_id', $warehouse_id)
    ->update(['product_qty' => $old_qty+$product_qty]);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try both ways:

```
DB::table('product_warehouse')
    ->where('product_id', $product_id)
    ->where('warehouse_id', $warehouse_id)
    ->update(['product_qty' => DB::raw('product_qty + ' . $product_qty)]);
```

Or

```
DB::table('product_warehouse')
    ->where('product_id', $product_id)
    ->where('warehouse_id', $warehouse_id)
    ->increment('product_qty', $product_qty);
```