# Laravel: Mass Updates

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Is there posible to do massive updates with different values, even using their own elements to find a new one?

For example

I have 100 productos and each one of them have their own price, if in some case i want to update that price in 5%, I'll have to get the oldest price, do the math and update the new one, and all of this in each one of them.

I was googling and I found [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#updates), but I'm not shure how to work with it.

I dont think it's a good idea to iterate all my products, get the price and update, This wont be efficient, so i think i need a builder, can u give me some ideas?

How to put this

```
  $prod->precio = ($prod->precio * ($porcentaje / 100)) + $prod->precio;
```

Right here

```
Producto_nombre::where('linea_id', $id)->update(['precio' => **here** ]);
```

Comment: check this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951180/laravel-query-builder-update-with-increment

Comment: Maybe using english column names, will make it easier to understand what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
Producto_nombre::where('linea_id', $id)->update(['precio' => DB::raw('(precio * ('.$porcentaje.' / 100)) + precio') ]);
```